# AngularJS add two classes and one with conditional

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I want to set an span 2 classes and one more with conditionality if item.qty is 0. I have this

```
<span ng-class="glyphicon,glyphicon-minus,{'notvisible': item.qty  0}"/>
```

But this dont work..i think this is not the sintax but i havent found anythink.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you just add those static classes in the usual way and only leave the conditional in an `ng-class`, like this:

```
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ng-class="{'notvisible': item.qty==0}"/>
```

Also, you forgot the compare-operator `==` (I added it in the above example).
If you only want to toggle the visibility of that element with the 'notvisible'-Class, I would even recommend you use the `ng-show`-Directive like this:

```
 <span ng-show="item.qty > 0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" />
```

Comment: With the ng-class of first example works fine. I cant use ng-show because i want to set visibility:hidden for keep the space.. With ng-show it eat the space.